# How to deal with hashed user credentials and Parse authentication

Tags: flutter, authentication, hash, parse-platform

I am trying to authenticate users for my Flutter app with hashed credentials. That is I'm hashing them before requesting auth with .login(). Problem is that the hashing packages I'm looking at using both have a function for checking the plain text password against the stored hash. This works fine for offline auth, however when sending hashed credentials to Parse auth gives invalid username/password error of course, because the algorithm changes after app restart.

The local side of things is pretty easy, now I'm caught wondering if it's secure to send users credentials in plain text through https Parse request?

I can't see a way to verify equality of hashing just entered credentials with parse because the hash is always different on app restart. Do I have any other option here?

Can someone give me some guidance here please?

Comment: You can use `.login()` method with plain text over https. That's the way it was designed to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the input Davi, I noticed you're a Parse engineer (very cool) could you elaborate a little on what happens behind the scenes please? Just out of curiosity, is there any additional layer of hash/encryption etc on client side and server side? Also I could not find anything about this in the docs. But then again maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: You're welcome. Behind the scenes, we store the password hash on the database. The password comes in plain text (over https though) from the client and we check the password against the hashed version we have stored in db.

Comment: Makes it nice and simple for me. Thanks for the info!